# Javascript: Clicking a button inside a div/form not executing the javascript meant for it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, getelementbyid

Okay, so I have a button inside a div. Here is that bit of HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <button type="button" id="submit">Send</button>
</div>
```

Before this button, there are other fields like name and email and stuff, and those are all inside a form, with the id "contactForm" (which is inside a div with class name "container").

I am making a JS file. I am trying to get it so that when the user puts in all the info like name & stuff, and hits submit, it will console.log() the name. That JS portion looks like this:

```
// Listen for submit btn click
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    console.log(name);
};
```

Right, so this part looks fine to me, but then when I go into the localhost where the website is, and i put in whatever random stuff into the name, email and message fields, and i hit submit, nothing happens.

The debugger/console says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

On line 48, which is this:

```
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
```

I started learning js today, so pretty new, but i cant find anything online that solves this problem. I found some that suggested i put the big JS portion inside a document.ready function, so it runs after everythings loaded. If I do that, which I tried, there is no error (like the line 48 one). It just doesnt say anything, and clicking on the btn doesnt do anything either (as in, doesnt show the name like i wanted).

Pls help, thanks.

Comment: As per the error message, the document.getElementById('contactForm') is returning null. In other words, it is unable to find the form element with id "contactForm". Please check once for any casing or spelling mistake.

Comment: where is your button ? is it inside form tage or outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the "Submit" event, you have to made a form which have `<input type="submit">`, your button with the id'submit' is not a valid submit button.

For simple, if you want the function to be executed when your button is clicked, just use this:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", function(){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this did it. Should've just checked for a click.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to attach an event even before the DOM has been loaded. You could use multiple solution for this.

1. Place your javascript code after the  tag.

   > ```
   > <form id='contactForm'></form>
   > <script>**** All your JavaScript goes here **** </script>
   > ```
2. Place your code inside **DOMContentLoaded** event.

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
       document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

have you checked your form's id for misspelling ?
also you can change a submit button to a simple div and add an onclick event handler instead if preventing default behavior. use it like this :

```js
document.getElementById('submit').onclick=function(){document.getElementById('my-test-p').innerHTML='Submit was clicked'}
```

```html
    <button type="button" id="submit">Send</button>
<p id='my-test-p'></p>
```